# Java ArrayList - Not Setting Existing Element

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, libgdx

When I try:

```
//Util.java

public static ArrayList<Sprite> Load(String[] path, int numOfFiles){
    ArrayList<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>(numOfFiles);
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++){
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(path[i]));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.flip(false, true);
        sprites.set(i, sprite);
    }
    return sprites;
}
```

I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

If I call:

```
//TheGame.java

ArrayList<Sprite> sprites;
String[] filenames = {"a.png", "b.png", "c.png"};

sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();

sprites.addAll(Util.Load(filenames, 3));
```

It should work because`numOfFiles`is`3`. I would prefer to use it the way I want. Why is it doing this?

I have changed it to this in the meantime, which works just fine.

```
//Util.java

public static ArrayList<Sprite> Load(String[] path, int numOfFiles){
    ArrayList<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
    Texture texture;
    Sprite sprite;
    for(int i = 0; i < numOfFiles; i++){
        texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(path[i]));
        texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
        sprite = new Sprite(texture);
        sprite.flip(false, true);
        sprites.add(sprite);
    }
    return sprites;
}
```

Comment: `I would prefer to use it the way I want` and why? Where do you see differences between both approaches?

Comment: @Tom : Well I want to allocate the memory first for a quicker load (say if there was 10 - 100 images to load). I see why it didn't work now thanks to Boann.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor [`new ArrayList<Sprite>(numOfFiles)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) does *not* create an ArrayList of size `numOfFiles`. It creates an ArrayList of size **0**, having an internal array whose *capacity* is `numOfFiles`. Since the list is empty, you can't set an element, since there is no element to set. The only purpose in providing a number to the ArrayList constructor is as an optimization to reduce internal array reallocation when the list grows.

The second version of the code in your question is correct. That's the way you should write it. You can optionally pass `numOfFiles` to the ArrayList constructor as an optimization to make sure it has an array of exactly the needed size, but you must still call `add` instead of `set`.

Comment: Thank you for that. You explained very clearly what I was doing wrong.

Comment: So does `ArrayList<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>(n);` allocate the memory for `n` amount of `sprites`?

Comment: @BReynolds Yes. Well, no. It allocates memory for `n` *pointers to* Sprites. The actual Sprite objects are created by the `new Sprite(...)` line.

Comment: Ah, so say if I had 100 Sprites or more. Would there be an advantage to having `new ArrayList<Sprite>(n)`.

Comment: @BReynolds Only a very tiny advantage. When an ArrayList's internal array needs to be expanded, it is expanded by 50%, and rounding odd numbers down. The default capacity for an empty ArrayList is 10. So it would allocate an array of size 10, for 10 pointers to Sprites, then expand it repeatedly to 15, 22, 33, 49, 73, and finally 109. By specifying the needed capacity in the constructor, you can avoid that reallocation. However, that reallocation has a very tiny cost compared to allocating all the Sprite objects themselves, loading the textures, parsing file paths and so on.

Comment: @BReynolds P.S. You actually don't need the `numOfFiles` variable, if you always want the function to use the full array. You can just use `path.length`. In that case you also don't need the `i` variable, because you can use the for-each statement to iterate the array instead: `for (String p : path) { texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal(p)); ...`

Comment: Awesome now I don't have to worry about forgetting to set that variable. I came from c/c++. I don't really know java that well yet. LibGDX was just too good to pass up so I'm learning it and Java.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Javadoc of ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set(int,%20E)) set:

> Replaces the element at the specified position in this list with the
>   specified element.

That is reason of `IndexOutOfBoundsException` since you're not calling `add` before calling `set`. **In short your list is still empty when `set` method is invoked**.

Answer (score 0):

You get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` because there was no element inside ArrayList when you try to replace an item by `sprites.set(i, sprite);`